# How to handle sql exception regarding encoding in netbeans ide 7.4?

Tags: encoding, netbeans-7, sqlexception

I am getting error when a user is attempting to login(after clicking login button) in my module like

`"java.sql.SQLException: [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.0.41-community-nt]`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'username=_latin1'abcd' and password=_latin1'abcd"`

Here abcd is the login username and password.I created mysql table for storing login details as follows:

```
create table userdetails(username varchar(20),password varchar(20));
```

And after clicking login button,values are inserted into the above table but it doesn't go the next page.
i set `ENCODING as UTF-8` to my project in `netbeans ide7.4` and I am getting same above error when I even tried with `ISO-8859-1` encoding. And I am using `jdk7` for my project.

Comment: Are you using MySQL 5.0.41 connector?

Comment: Ya.I am using MYSQL CONNECTOR/ODBC 5.1